# Active Record find_by returns null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I cant seem to get find_by to work, when you query the results like

GET /users.json?first_name=Tyrone&last_name=Slothrop"

should return Users whose first_name is Tyrone and whose last_name is Slothrop.

It returns null because all the params are null in that query except first_name and last_name. Im stuck as to get it to accept the only the query params and search by those. any advice?

```
  class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.find_by(id: params[:id], first_name: params[:first_name], 
                            last_name: params[:last_name], email: params[:email],
                            city: params[:city], state: params[:state])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @users.to_json, status: :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

here is a link to mt full repo https://github.com/jslack2537/apiDemoApp

dev log output for request

```
Started GET "/api/v1/users.json?first_name=Tyrone&last_name=Slothrop" for 10.0.2.2 at 2020-04-01 02:42:17 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"first_name"=>"Tyrone", "last_name"=>"Slothrop"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (4.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL AND "users"."first_name" = ? AND "users"."last_name" = ? AND "users"."email" IS NULL AND "users"."city" IS NULL AND "users"."state" IS NULL LIMIT ?[0m  [["first_name", "Tyrone"], ["last_name", "Slothrop"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:5
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
```

EDIT***  I now receive this error with my updated code
NoMethodError (undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass):

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    ids = params[:id].split(",")
    if params[:id].present?
  @users = User.where(user_params.merge!(id: ids)).paginate(:per_page => params[:size], :page => params[:page]).order('id DESC')
   respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @users.to_json, status: :ok }
    end
   else
    @users = User.where(user_params).paginate(:per_page => params[:size], :page => params[:page]).order('id DESC')
    respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render json: @users.to_json, status: :ok }
     end
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
   params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :city, :state)
  end
end
```

Comment: how are you sending the request? Also if you take a look at the rails server log, what are you getting, I'm guesing you are receiving unpermitted parameters, can you verify the logs?

Comment: Im using postman to send the request, and heres what the log outputs on the request
ill add it to the bottom of my original post

Comment: I just cloned your repo and made it work, check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should permit the params, I downloaded your repo and I was able to get the desired query by permitting the params, like this:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @users = User.find_by(user_params)
  respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: @users.to_json, status: :ok }
  end
 end

 private

 def user_params
  params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :city, :state)
 end
end
```

Now if you try this query `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users?first_name=Tyrone&last_name=Slothrop&city=Chicago` you should see on the logs that the only the params that you passed are being used for the search:

```
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."first_name" = ? AND "users"."last_name" = ? AND "users"."email" = ? AND "users"."city" = ? LIMIT ?  [["first_name", "Tyrone"], ["last_name", "Slothrop"], ["email", "jean@email.com"], ["city", "Chicago"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

↳ app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:11

Rails is just permitting the params defined on the user_params, so if they're not present, it will just be ignored

Edit: TO return the list of matches you should use where:

```
  def index
   @users = User.where(user_params)
   respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @users.to_json, status: :ok }
   end
  end
```

To allow multiple parameters, for example to allow for multiple first_name fields you can do:

```
  def user_params
   params.permit(:last_name, :email, :city, :state, first_name: [])
  end
```

Remember to put your array items in the end of the permit to avoid syntax errors, and after that you can query the first name like this: `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users?first_name[]=John&first_name[]=Jean`,

That url can get pretty tedious to build, so I would suggest that if you are building an api you can always send the params in the body of the request, like this:

```
{
 "first_name": ["John", "Jean"]
}
```

And that will have the exact behavior of passing the params in the url.

If you strictly want to send the id like id=1,2,3 that you can do something like:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

 def index
  ids = params[:id].split(",")
  @users = User.where(user_params.merge!(id: ids))
  respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: @users.to_json, status: :ok }
  end
 end

 private

 def user_params
  params.permit(:last_name, :email, :city, :state, :first_name)
 end
end
```

The user_params.merge! will do the trick since it will overwrite or add the id key to your user_params hash.

Comment: so this works and it doesn't i have to be able to filter on any of those params so http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users?first_name=Tyrone&last_name=Slothrop&city=Chicago may be null but http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users?first_name=Tyrone&last_name=Slothrop&city=Chicagohttp://localhost:3000/api/v1/users?state="Arkansas" should return all users that have arkansas as their state also if you query by id like http://localhost:3030/api/v1/users.json?id=1,2,3,4 it should return all four users not just the first

Comment: You should use where instead of find_by because find by returns the first matching record, where will return all the matches

Comment: well there is this request http://localhost:3030/api/v1/users.json?id=1,2,3,4   this still wont return the first 4 users

Comment: If you want to allow params you need to permit them like this: params.permit(:last_name, :email, :city, :state, id: [], first_name: []) and in the query you should add this in order to make rails aware that you're sending arrays api/v1/users?id[]=2&id[]=1&first_name[]=John&first_name[]=Jean. Notice the brackets after the id and first_name, this will tell rails that you're sending multiple items for a particular field.

Comment: This does work but i need it accept the params like .json?id=1,2,3,4

Comment: I updated my code to give you an idea of how can you accomplish the multiple ids if they're send in that format.

Comment: If query something without an id now it returns this also you have been awesome at helping with this 
NoMethodError (undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: I would just add a validation to check if the params[:id].present? And if they are not just send the regular params without the id field

Comment: I update my code in my original post im still recieving the no method error i may be validating incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

I can see an error in the way you are sending the request to the API

> try: /users.json?first_name=Tyrone&last_name=Slothrop"
>   instead of: /users.jsonfirst_name=Tyrone&last_name=Slothrop"

do you see the missing "?" at the begining of the query string?

---

Edit after fix the request url:

maybe the best approach for your query is use where instead of find_by.
example:

```
user = User.where(id: params[:id])
.where(first_name: params[:first_name])
.where(last_name: params[:last_name])
.where(email: params[:email])
.where(city: params[:city])
.where(state: params[:state])
.first
```

Comment: Yeah I just forgot to type that in here I'm using it to send the request I fixed the post

Comment: maybe the best approach for your query is use where instead of find_by

Comment: For ActiveRecord `where(...).first` = `find_by(...)`.

Comment: As Sebastian says, find_by and where are almost 100% percent equal, with the difference that ".where().first" adds an "order by" clause to the final SQL that the active records sends to the database, but the main difference of course is in the ruby syntax, using where() you can build more readable code.